# Finding $\frac{3}{1!+2!+3!}+\frac{4}{2!+3!+4!} +\frac{5}{3!+4!+5!}+\cdots+\frac{2008}{2006!+2007!+2008!}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, factorial

How to find :

$$\frac{3}{1!+2!+3!}+\frac{4}{2!+3!+4!} +\frac{5}{3!+4!+5!}+\cdots+\frac{2008}{2006!+2007!+2008!}$$