# A sum of series problem: $\frac{3}{1!+2!+3!} + \frac{4}{2!+3!+4!} + \cdots + \frac{2008}{2006!+2007!+2008!}$

Tags: summation, factorial

I have a question regarding the sum of this series:
$$\frac{3}{1!+2!+3!} + \frac{4}{2!+3!+4!} + \cdots + \frac{2008}{2006!+2007!+2008!}$$
My approach:
I found that this sum is equal to:
$$\sum_{n=3}^{2008}\frac{n}{(n-2)!+(n-1)!+(n)!}$$

I reduced it to :
$$\sum_{n=3}^{2008}\frac{1}{n(n-2)!}$$
 Please suggest how to proceed further.

Comment: This seems to be basically the same question as [Help with difficult telescoping series question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1068566) and [finding $\frac{3}{1!+2!+3!}+\frac{4}{2!+3!+4!} +\frac{5}{3!+4!+5!}+\cdots+\frac{2008}{2006!+2007!+2008!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/202924) Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B1!%2B2!%2B3!%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What we want is $$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \dfrac{n+2}{n! + (n+1)! +(n+2)!}$$
\begin{align}
\dfrac{n+2}{n! + (n+1)! +(n+2)!} & = \dfrac{n+2}{n! \left( 1 + (n+1) + (n+1)(n+2) \right)}\\
& = \dfrac{n+2}{n! \left( n^2 + 4n + 4 \right)}\\
& = \dfrac1{n! \left( n+2 \right)}\\
& = \dfrac{n+1}{(n+2)!}\\
& = \dfrac{n+2}{(n+2)!} - \dfrac1{(n+2)!}\\
& = \dfrac1{(n+1)!} - \dfrac1{(n+2)!}
\end{align}

Can you finish it off from here?

Move your mouse over the gray area below for the complete answer.

> \begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \dfrac{n+2}{n! + (n+1)! +(n+2)!} & = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \left( \dfrac1{(n+1)!} - \dfrac1{(n+2)!}\right)\\ & = \left( \dfrac1{2!} - \dfrac1{3!} + \dfrac1{3!} - \dfrac1{4!} + \dfrac1{4!} - \dfrac1{5!} + \cdots + \dfrac1{(N+1)!} - \dfrac1{(N+2)!}\right)\\ & = \dfrac1{2!} - \dfrac1{(N+2)!}\end{align} Set $N=2006$ to get the answer to your question.

Comment: What should $n$ replaced by ?

Comment: @spa $N = 2006$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Apply telescoping series to
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{2006}\frac{k+2}{k!+(k+1)!+(k+2)!}
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2006}\frac{k+2}{k!\,(k+2)^2}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2006}\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2006}\left(\frac1{(k+1)!}-\frac1{(k+2)!}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: elegant and concise

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac1{n(n-2)!}=\dfrac{n-1}{n!}$$
which is Telescoping

Comment: Thanks, how did you telescope it?

Comment: Drake write out a few terms, they start cancelling.

Comment: Yes, they start cancelling out when I write out a few terms of RHS, but how do you convert LHS to RHS( using partial fractions?)

Comment: @drake01 I'd say it comes by practice and fiddling out with the few terms given. You know this is _not_ a standard sequence. So, the next obvious way is to try see if the sequence can telescope. You try out a few techniques, multiply $(n-1)$ in both the numerator and denominator, and it works! As noted on MSE before, call it the maths of "wishful thinking" ^_^

Comment: You are right, @Gaurang,

Comment: I had unknowingly converted it into RHS form before, but didn't put the values to check if it telescopes or not.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=3}^{2008}\frac{1}{n(n-2)!}=\sum_{n=3}^{2008}\frac{1}{n(n-2)!}.\frac{(n-1)}{(n-1)}=\sum_{n=3}^{2008}\frac{n-1}{n!}=\sum_{n=3}^{2008}(\frac{n}{n!}-\frac{1}{n!})=\sum_{n=3}^{2008}(\frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\frac{1}{n!})=\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{4!}+...-\frac{1}{2007!}+\frac{1}{2007!}-\frac{1}{2008!}=\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{2008!}$

Comment: The matter of fun is , I had obtained  $\sum\frac{n-1}{n!}$ earlier then converted it into,$\sum\frac{1}{n(n-2)!}$ and then posted in MSE. Because the concept of Telescoping series didn't struck me at the moment. btw thanks.

Comment: @drake01 We all gradually gain the experience. The sweet part is these things, yes so funny. LOL :D